# Will 16.04 Unity 7 improvements be available in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, 16.04

I was wondering if the Unity 7 improvements made in 16.04 will be available in 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 14.04 is an LTS release and some programs may depending on the behavior how ubuntu 14.04 LTS does or does not things generally most of programs and libraries will stay in its major release and only minor updates or security fixes would be apllied to the distri.

Shorthand answer: Unity Enhancement of 16.04 would not be backported to 14.04 LTS

[excerpt from ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS):

> Release Plan Details
>   We start stabilizing the release early by significantly limiting the number of new features. We will choose which features we package into the LTS release, versus which ones we leave out and allow for users to optionally download and use from a separate archive.
>
> Avoid structural changes as far as possible, such as changing the default set of applications, lots of library transitions, or system layer changes (example: introducing KMS or hal → DeviceKit would not have been appropriate changes in a LTS).
>
> ### Furthermore, we define the LTS to be:
>
> **Enterprise Focused:** We are targeting server and multiple desktop installations, where the average user is moderately risk averse.
>
> **Compatible with New Hardware:** We will make point releases throughout the development cycle to provide functional support for new server and desktop hardware.
>
> **More Tested:** We will shorten the development window and extend the Beta cycle to allow for more testing and bug fixing
>
> ### and clearly state that it is not:
>
> **A Feature-Based Release:** We will focus on hardening functionality of existing features, versus introducing new ones1, except for in the areas of Online Services and Desktop Experience.
>
> 1. Exceptions for priority projects will be documented.
> 2. Because these two areas of development are relatively new, they still require new features to satisfy the original reasons for their creation